# Building a tree from depth-first traversal of graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have written the following algorithm pseudocode to depth-first traverse an undirected connected graph $G = (V, E)$:

```
DFS(G, v):
  T = (V' = {v}, E' = empty, v)
  s = [] // stack with push and pop
  visited = [] // array with append and size
  all_visited = [] // array
  for u in {u | uv in E}:
    s.push(u)
  while s != []:
    u = s.pop()
    visited.append(u)
    L = {w | uw in E and w not in s + visited + all_visited}
    if |L| == 0:
      T = (V' + visited, E' + {u_iu_(i+1) | i < visited.size() and u_i, u_(i+1) in visited}, v)
      for w in visited:
         all_visited.append(w)
      visited = [v]
    else:
      for w in L:
        s.append(w)
  return T
```

Now while this function is correct in the sense that it does traverse all vertices that are reachable from $v$, it doesn't build the tree correctly. What am I missing to fix it so it works as intended?

EDIT: New algorithm. Since $G$ is finite, assume $V = \{1, ..., n\}$

```
DFS(G, v):
  V' = {v}
  E' = {}
  visited = [v]
  s = []
  for u in {u in V | uv in E}:
    s.push(u)

  while s != []:
    u = s.pop()
    visited.append(u)
    L = {w in V' | wu in E}
    w = min(L)
    E' = E' ∪ {{u, w}}
    V' = V' ∪ {u}
    for w in L:
      if w not in visited ∪ s:
        s.push(w)

  return (V, E, v)
```

This algorithm constructs the correct rooted tree as far as I can tell. Is it correct?

Comment: I do know that the current way I construct new edges doesn't really make sense but I had to put something there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a depth-first traverse, just another valid traverse. In depth-first search we visit all non-visited vertices that are reachable from a vertex $v$ right after the vertex $v$. And here you skip vertices that are already stacked, even if they wouldn't be stacked now in recursive version of DFS. So the simplest graph for which we have difference is $C_{3} = v_0v_1v_2v_0$: correct $\mathrm{DFS}(G, v_0)$ would produce the path $v_0v_1v_2$, while your traverse is the path $v_1v_0v_2$.

Comment: I have updated the pseudocode